# Sharepoint Online - Calendar View - Cannot add entries due to "List does not exist" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I can no longer add entries in the default "Normal Calendar" view. I get the following error:

> "List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. (f06d3f9e-
>   d01a-5000-f009-cf2f4496eff8)"

Any suggestions to a fix is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it sounds like someone has deleted the calendar.  Are you able to access 'site content' - you can see all calendars, lists and libraries by looking there

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tally. Yes I can see the calendar in 'site content'. I can also add entries to the calendar through the list view. Issue only seems to occur when I try to add en entry through the calendar view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In SharePoint Online**, Try to investigate the issue by doing the following:

1. Make sure that the list is not already deleted!
2. Make sure you have sufficient permission (at least read).
3. Try to open the `Maintenance page` by adding the `?contents=1` at the end of the current URL,

   ```
   https://YourURL/page.aspx?Contents=1
   ```

   Make sure that the list web part is listed!

   - If it's listed, check it, then click on delete button, then go back to the main page to add it again as the following:

     - Edit the page.
     - Click on Add web part.
     - At App Part > Select your Calander list web part > Insert.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohamed. 

1. List isn't deleted as I can add entries through the list view to the calendar. 
2. I have admin access.
3. Web part is appearing on Maintenance page

Comment: try to delete it from  from the maintenance page  then add it again

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I deleted the web part and added it again. No longer getting the error. thanks for your help!